# HTML 5 Storage Application Cache Manifest file location

Tags: java, javascript, tomcat6, html5-appcache

I am developing a web application on Tomcat 6 that needs a dynamic application cache. I need to be able to modify contents of the manifest file (add new file locations or remove existing ones) via a servlet in my application.

I want to store the file external to the application on the server or on another server.

1. Can I specify the following in the page that uses the cache

   `<html manifest="http://some-other-server/some-path/xyz.appcache">`
2. Can I store it on the same server at a location out of the deployed war file, in that case, how do I specify the manifest path?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Hava a look at this site which lists some facts about application cache - http://appcachefacts.info/

For your answer:

1. You are referencing the manifest file from another origin. It's not allowed.
2. Yes, you can store it on same server and for using that you could have a redirect servlet. In you web.xml you'd have:

   ```
   <servlet>
     <servlet-name>ManifestServlet</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>com.example.ManifestServlet</servlet-class>
   </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>ManifestServlet</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>{Your-Manifest-Url-pattern}</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
   ```

Through this ManifestServlet you can serve the manifest-file from any where on the server.